# Bootstrap Modals on Owl-Carousel images on mobile iOS

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal, owl-carousel

**Small but annoying issue:**

I have a scrolling gallery using the jquery owl-carousel plugin. When an image in the carousel is clicked, it is intended to pop up a modal. On desktop this works properly - on mobile it is buggy.

After scrolling by dragging the images, the images are SOMETIMES not tappable unless tapped several times. It will work after a few taps and pop up the modal, but is very inconsistent.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

(I can reproduce the issue with the code below in chrome dev tools > toggle device toolbar to iPhone)

```js
$('.loop').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    nav:true,
    items:2,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsive:{
        600:{
            items:4
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>





         <div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme">
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal1">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal2">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal3">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal4">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" >
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal5">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" >
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal6">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal7">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal8">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
             <div class="item">
               <div class="CarouselImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GModal9">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" >
                
               </div>
             </div>
          
         </div>







<div class="modal fade" id="GModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800"  />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800" />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800"  />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800" />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal5">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800"  />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal6">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800" />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal7">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800" />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal8">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800" />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="GModal9">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="GalleryModalHolder">
        <img class="GalleryModalImg" src="https://placehold.it/800x800"  />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>















<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for responsive implementation of bootstrap so wrap div for grid based implementation with container,column,row etc with different screen col size,also make following change in **responsiveClass:true,**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1,
        nav:true
    },
    600:{
        items:3,
        nav:false
    },
    1000:{
        items:5,
        nav:true,
        loop:false
    }
}
})
```

Comment: There is no issue with the way it looks on smaller screens, just the tapping functionality. `responsiveClass:true` did not fix this.